PNG logo appears on the rear side of the node set up
I have a node set up, PBR material, and I'm applying a PNG logo to the cube. The PNG logo, appears on the front side of the cube, but it also appears on the rear of the cube. How can I have the logo just appear on one side?



Is the cube rotated? Because when I use the General coordinates the image texture appears on the top and bottom, not front and back.

Yes, its rotated X=90
https://ibb.co/NSh10Ft

Typically, the logo decal would be in UV space, not in XY or whatever of Generated space. The XY of a 3D space is a projection through it. It doesn't know anything about 'Front' or 'Back'. You could wrangle a mask, but (mapped 2D) UV would be easier.

Is this the method with the 2D-UV projection, you suggested? I had to play around with the Mapping location and scale to adjust the Logo, because when I tried with the UV editor to adjust the logo, the bricks on the logo side would also scale up and down. So Mapping the node with the PNG also got me a correct result, if this was what you had in mind.
https://ibb.co/4SkRZLx

As I said in my comment, it seems your cube is rotated, because using the Generated coordinates like this should result in having the image on the top and bottom, not front and back. But anyway, if it is not rotated you might just change an axis in the following solution.
In my example I have a PNG with some text on transparent background. I mix it over the brick texture by its alpha channel like you. Since I'm using Generated texture coordinates, the text is visible at the top and bottom, here are two cubes with the material, one is turned upside down:

The Generated coordinates (without any changed mapping) always range from 0 to 1 on each axis. This means, on the cube the value on the Z axis goes from 0 at the bottom to 1 at the top. If you use a Separate XYZ node and plug it in a Math node set to Greater Than with a Threshold of 0.5, the bottom half is black (0 or false) and the top half is white (1 or true):

So the easiest thing to separate top and bottom now is to multiply the Alpha output with the result of the Greater Than comparison. The bottom half will be multiplied with 0 and therefore show the brick texture:

As mentioned at the beginning, if you would not have rotated the cube and you had the image on front and back, you might have to use another axis like X. Also the Threshold value might be changing if you used some mapping for the image (I've seen you have moved and scaled it a bit) which moved the coordinates up or down or anything. This method of separating the Generated coordinates and using them as a mask would also work if you placed images with a UV map on an object, since you can always use multiple outputs of the Texture Coordinate node for different operations.
By the way, if you are not using UV mapping for the logo because you do not want to mess up the UVs for the base texture, you can always create more than one UV map for an object. Instead of using the UV output of the Texture Coordinate node you would then use a UV Map node and choose the one you need for the corresponding image.

The Separate Node with the other 2 maths node, did the trick. Thanks.
